# Take specific bands from multiple rasters and stack them into one new raster

Tags: raster, gdal, netcdf

Is there an existing function in GDAL that allows selecting specific bands from multiple rasters to combine?

The rasters are identical in other ways like alignment and coordinate system and extent.

The data is actually in NetCDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select one or several bands from source images with gdal_translate https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html

> -b
>
> Select an input band band for output. Bands are numbered from 1.
> Multiple -b switches may be used to select a set of input bands to
> write to the output file, or to reorder bands. band can also be set to
> “mask,1” (or just “mask”) to mean the mask band of the first band of
> the input dataset.

The output is a single image but if the output is a virtual raster (VRT) the it is just a small XML file that does not take much space. Then you can combine the extracted bands together with gdal_merge.py https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html by using the `-separate` option

> -separate
>
> Place each input file into a separate band.

Or perhaps with gdalbuildvrt https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html, also by using the `-separate` option.

Answer (score 0):

Picking and choosing specific bands from different rasters and combining them together seems a bit tricky

So far the best I've found is making a virtual raster of each band you want from each raster with
`-b 1`
etc.

Then you can combine them by making another .vrt with `-separate`

Finally you can put this into gdal_translate and use `-colorinterp_X` to assign the right interpretation to each band